# Mismatch in area calculation using R and ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, r, spatial-statistics, rgeos

I am new to spatial statistics using R. In this scenario, I am trying to calculate the polygons area with in a shapefile by using`rgeos::gArea` and compared with ArcMap calculate geometry value. both the values are of a lot.

```
NAME        RG_NAME     _ABBREV     AREA      AREA_cal_ByR
Addison      Texas        TX        3.718831  13719277
Carrollton   Texas        TX        17.061196 62942062
Carrollton   Texas        TX        12.675647 46807613
```

ArcMap Calculated area is of column name "AREA", which is in Square Miles and here is projected coordinated system of the shapefile `CRS arguments:
 +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0
+y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs`

can someone guide me, where i am doing it wrong.

Here is the Rcode that used for area calculation -

```
inter_zips_within$AREA_clip <- round(rgeos::gArea(inter_zips_within, byid = T), 2)
inter_zips_within@proj4string
```

Comment: I guess that you have somehow calculated the small numbers by using square degrees (longitude x latitude) as area unit.

Comment: What are the units of your dataframe in ArcMap? Do those numbers seem reasonable for the area in square miles

Comment: @user30184 small units were calculated in square mile units. But I am not sure about area calculation by rgeos::gArea.

Comment: @lambertj.  yes!!. The calculation by ArcMap seems reasonable.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the code you are using in R to calculate the area? Perhaps that's where the problem is then if the values from ArcMap seem good.

Comment: For rgeos:gArea, area units is by default the units of your projection. From your CRS argument, it seems Area is calculated in square meters. (units=m).

Comment: The question I would ask first is if it is desirable to calculate area using a web-mercator projection? The answer is usually NO! So even if you get the two calculations to produce similar results, the areas will be too large (getting worse towards the poles). Some equal area projection would give more reliable results.

Answer (score 1):

While the major difference can be attributed to the units, the measurement *type* may have something to do with it as well. There are different ways to calculate area http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/measuring-distances-and-areas.htm. Do you know whether you are being consistent in your measurement type (i.e. geodesic, planar, etc.)?

Considering your projection, I would recommend trying to calculate area using the geodesic method. In Arcmap, you can use the field calculator and the Python Parser with the following statement:

```
!Shape!.getArea("GEODESIC","SQUAREMILES")
```

It doesn't look like this parameter is available in the R package, but try it with arc, make sure your units are the same, and then see how the values compare.

Answer (score 0):

While Mercator area may be meaningless, as TimSalabim points out, the likely explanation of the difference would be a difference in units, as Jelle suggests. One would think that the arc numbers are in miles2 and the R data in m2. However, the numbers do not support this:

```
arc <- c(3.718831,17.061196,12.675647)
r <- c(13719277, 62942062, 46807613)
arc * 1609.34^2 / r
#[1] 0.7020545 0.7020437 0.7013733
```

That's pretty mysterious. At least the ratio is constant (assuming the difference are due to rounding).

By the way, a simpler and more general (as it also works for lon/lat data) way to compute area for SpatialPolygons is

```
library(raster)
p$area <- area(p)
```